# Google form embedded HTML not loading in email

Tags: html, forms, iframe, google-forms

I have a google form embedded into an email template. It's for security approvals and I just want the user to select approve or do not approve but when the email is sent the area for the form just says loading... and never displays to form no matter how long I wait. My issues are with the iframe I think.

A user has submitted a security request pending your approval

Loading...

A user has submitted a security request pending your approval

(<)iframe src="https://docs.google.com/a/gkservices.com/forms/d/18Q1RQ-iATvM6EZehWs5-zr5x7PNi0uePuF-Uwy_CRZE/viewform?embedded=true" width="760" height="780" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...(<)/iframe>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html IFrame tag is not being interpret in email body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652770/html-iframe-tag-is-not-being-interpret-in-email-body)

Answer (score 2):

Quite likely, the email client doesn't support `iframe` - this is a [fairly](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2010/08/do-iframes-work-in-email/) [common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976966/how-to-display-iframe-tag-to-gmail) problem as many clients don't support it. From security to anti-spam, `iframe` is email is a fairly bad idea, so it doesn't have widespread support.

If you want to ensure compatibility, you have have to live with just including a link to the form.